# Default application for opening files in network folder LTS 20

Tags: networking, nautilus, 20.04, default

how can I set the default application for files in network folder? I use LTS 20.04 and using the network folder manager of Nautilus. When I mount a folder through "+ Other Locations -> Connect to Server" it wont use my default applications as on my local folder.

The folder is mounted through such a link "/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=*".

But when I want to open a file e.g. with the ending .out it wont use gedit as default like it is set for my local files. It even doesnt save it as default application when I browse through "Select Application".

On LTS 18 everything works fine and it uses all my default applications as its set for local folders.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this problem too. I didn't really use Ubuntu 18.04 but went from 16.04 straight to 20.04 but I thought I had the same problem in 18.04, though it could have been a slightly earlier or later release.

I am also sure that I looked for a solution and found a post which had a solution but it was not trivial. I have looked hard for it just now but I can't find it again.

The only solution I have is to right mouse on the file you want to open, click 'Open With Other Application', then choose the application. The application you choose may well be the one it listed as the default, but I found that I have to go through that whole process to get it to work as you would expect. Currently with my GDrive mapped, Nautilus opens (double left click) all my text files in Chrome (and then says it can't) instead of the default Geany. Right clicking and choosing 'Open with Geany' opens it in Chrome.

Sorry, if you already knew that. If I do come across that other post I will update this.